# Android checkbox checked in one activity and then text appears in another activity that notifies that checkbox has been checked

Tags: android

So I have one activity with a checkbox and a button and another activity with a textview.
When I check the checkbox and click the button, the button calls startActivty(intent) which starts the other activity with the textview and should inform the user with a text that the checkbox was checked. How do I do this?

Comment: When the button is clicked, read the checkbox's state and pass the value to other activity in the intent's extras. Maybe you should read few android tutorials because that seems to be pretty common task and google has full of examples of passing data between activities. For example [http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Before starting another activity, pass checkbox checked are not as extran in bundled assuming 1 for checked.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FindAndroidActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Checkbox","1");
```

In your other activity, get that value

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString("Checkbox");
 //Check if value is '1', if so, it is checked and add whatever text you want to textbox here.
}
```

Comment: Just an addition to above: if the text for the CheckBox is static, you could just pass on a boolean value to simplify the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.putExtra("Checked",true);
```

and then start your activity with this intent. In second activity override Activity .onStart()

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    Bundle bundle=getIntent.getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null){
        if(bundle.getBoolean("Checked")) /*do your stuff*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Only one thing. When I leave the activity with the textview and come back to it the text i have set isn't there anymore.

Comment: It's another question. Read about saving activity state.